# What are different approaches for address translations?

Tags: nat

What are different approaches for address translations and which approach in your opinion should be preferred and why?

Comment: Could you add some more detail? What exactly are you trying to do? What sort of info are you looking for? What operating system(s) are you using?

Comment: I am just trying to understand the science/approaches behind NAT, i know there are several implementations like address restricted cone etc, but i am not sure how they differ and which one is the best/most popular.

Comment: This wouldn't be a homework question, would it? It sorta sounds like one.

Comment: well it kinda is .. i am trying to learn more about networks, cause i am basically a programmer myself .. so yeah you can call it homework :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Address Restricted Cone" and its bretheren were names given to theoretical types of NAT that were described in the STUN protocol. As far as I'm aware none of them made it past a piece of paper.

Everything (and more) you can learn about NAT is currently on [the wikipedia artical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). Normally I hate linking to Wikipedia, but in this case it's probably going to be far more educational than here.